# Resultado - .find() - Diferente do esperado

Tags: python

Quando eu rodo esse código:

```
fname = input('File name: ')
fhand = open(fname)
count = 0
for line in fhand:
    if line.find('Subject:'):
        count = count + 1
print('There were', count, 'subjects lines in ', fname)
```

Com o input: mbox-short.txt (Link abaixo)
Output correto: 27
Output atual: 1883

Não faço a mínima ideia do porque.
[link do arquivo txt](https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt)
py version: 3.8.3 - Nem sei porque estou usando essa versão, se você tiver alguma opnião sobre isso por favor, comente

Comment: Quanto a versão do Python: 3.8.3 é bem atual, e é a indicada pra usar. Há poucos dias saiu a versão 3.9.0  - quando quiser, e principalmente se for começar um novo projeto, pode fazer a atualização para a série 3.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método `str.find` retorna a posição da primeira ocorrência da string desejada ou -1 quando não encontrada.

O problema principal é que você fez apenas `if line.find('Subject:')`. Quando não encontrado, o retorno é -1, que é avaliado como `True` no Python. Apenas o número zero é avaliado como `False`. Ou seja, para todas as linhas que ele não encontrar a string irá contabilizar na sua variável; e se encontrar, mas for no início, o retorno será 0 e não contabilizará.

Basta, então, corrigir a sua condição para:

```
if line.find('Subject:') >= 0:
    count = count + 1
```